# How to concatenate matrices horizontally?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two *3*-by-*3* matrices:

```
A= [ 1 2 3 
     1 1 1
     0 1 1] 

B= [ 1 2 1 
     1 1 1
     2 2 2]
```

How do I concatenate the `A` and `B` matrices to create the `concat` matrix as seen below?

```
concat= [1 2 3 1 2 1
         1 1 1 1 1 1
         0 1 1 2 2 2]
```

Comment: Use `horzcat(A,B)` as suggested, it is likely the fastest alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities here. The easiest, and most common one:

```
concat = [A, B]
```

The following is considered more robust by some, (because one might, on accident, do `concat = [A; B]`, which would concatenate them vertically):

```
concat = horzcat(A, B)
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply do:

```
concat = [A B];
```

This will make a new matrix that pieces `A` and `B` together horizontally (i.e. concatenates).

Another possibility is to use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) where you specify the second dimension (column-wise) to concatenate the two matrices together.

```
concat = cat(2, A, B);
```

Alternatively you can use [`horzcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) as alluded by a few people here.  This essentially is syntactic sugar for `cat` in the second dimension.

```
concat = horzcat(A, B);
```